# Building libgit2 static libraries with brew

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew, libgit2

I would like to build static libraries of libgit2 with brew. By default, the binaries only include dynamic libs:

```
brew install libgit2
```

According to libgit2 documentation, we need to pass `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` to cmake. How do I make brew pass an argument to cmake? I tried:

```
brew install libgit2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF --build-from-source
```

But that did not do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` to the cmake arguments used in the [libgit2](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libgit2.rb) [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#formula-cookbook) you use:

```
def install
  args = std_cmake_args
  ...
  args << "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF"
  ...
```

Comment: Yes but how do I pass that through brew?

Comment: you will have to edit the formula.  Type "brew edit libgit2". This would display a ruby file. Include the code shared by Peter into the file.

Comment: @Peter, once I edit the formula with 'brew edit ...' how do we trigger it again?

Comment: I hate it when I try to figure something out and I had the last comment... but I guess it is better than being the OP

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me, if you are interested only in generating static library, you can try this.**

1. Install libgit2 using brew

> brew install libgit2

**This will install all the dependencies needed to build libgit2**

2. Download libgit2 code from https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 and compile it manually. Follow these steps:

> cd SOURCE_DIRECTORY
>
> mkdir build
>
> **// Do this if you want to install binaries into a local folder.**
>
> mkdir install
>
> cd build
>
> cmake ..  -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64"  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/SOURCE_DIRECTORY/install -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
>
> cmake --build . --target install

**"-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX"** specifies the folder into which you want to install the binaries. Pick any folder.

This generated the static library at "**/SOURCE_DIRECTORY/install/lib**" folder